# A JS function to fetch first excessive argument of another function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Got myself an interesting little quest:
build a JS function that, when called from within another function, returns **first excessive argument** that was passed to that function.

E.g.

```
/**
* Returns first excessive argument of a function, if any
* @param {function} context - function to refer to
*/ 
function getExcessiveArgument( context ){
   // I know I cannot access arguments and length like that, 
   // but that's what I'd do if I could.
   // arguments being the array of all arguments, 
   // length - the number of expected arguments
   return context.arguments[ context.length ]; 
}

function ReturnExcessive(a,b){
   // this is NOT correct as well, 
   // but I would pass called function's context there, if I could
   return getExcessiveArgument( this );  
}

ReturnExcessive( 1,2,7); // Should return 7
```

An alternative could be calling the **getExcessiveArgument** function with **arguments** and **length**, but I cannot figure out how to access **length** even from within the parent function.

Is it at all possible to write a function like this in JS or am I wasting my time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK for `function f(a, b) {}` the call `f(1, 2, 7)` has `7` being excessive. What about `function g(a, b = 0) {}` in the call `g(1, 2, 7)` is `2` or `7` the first excessive argument?

Comment: @VLAZ yah, function.length stops working on first parameter with default value, so according to JS 2 and 7 are not excessive arguments in this case. Unfortunately.
It actually kills the whole idea, so I guess what I've been trying to figure out is not possible at all.

Comment: That is correct, `fn.length` only counts the declared non-defaulted parameters. Also won't record if you have `function foo() { return arguments[0] + arguments[1]}` - since the function doesn't *declare* parameters, `length` would be zero, even if it uses `arguments` to get the first two. Also, `length` is going to be inaccurate with rest parameters `function bar(a, ...b) {}`. Hence, why it's important to understand what is considered "excessive" or not. If it doesn't coincide with JS's `fn.length` then you can use an AST parser on the function definition to examine the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a copy of `arguments` and slice with the function's `length` of defined parameters.

```js
function fn(a, b) {
    return [...arguments].slice(fn.length);
}

console.log(fn(1, 2, 7)); // 7
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks!
Now, can there be a function that grabs that from within fn() ?